# Target option is disabled in Eclipse window->Preference->android

Tags: android, eclipse

Why my target option in eclipse is disabled? I cant select the target platform.
On the other hand the platform folder and adds-on are empty.
Plz any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After you have installed your SDK, you need to download all the platforms you need (like Android 1.5, Google API's, so on...)

Then you should create some virtual devices with some parameters (like screen size, sd card...). Then you should run the app over the platform you like.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to install required platforms.

```
Eclipse > Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager > Available Packages ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem. The Android SDK archive does not come populated with a specific Android platform or Google add-on. We can use the SDK Manager to install or update SDK components such as platforms,tools, add-ons, and documentation. I used the eclipse tooling option path provided by the first answer. There is also a "SDK Manager.exe" file that can be used to download outside eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the complete API that you're working on.

Suppose, In my case I am working on **Android 5.0 SDK Tools** and I Froyo 2.2 for minimum SDK Verison support. So Now I have 2 SDK Tools Installed, Android 5.0 and Android 2.2.

To make them support as Target SDK, I need to install the complete package from Android SDK Manager.[image]

**In your case install the complete package of the respective API you're using. After installing, restart eclipse and then your Target Option will be enabled.**